# Struct array initialization inside class ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with initialization of array in class array, I have a SearchArrayModel:

```
public class SearchArrayModel
{
    public struct AttribStruct
    {
        public string AttribName { get; set; }
        public string[] AttribValues { get; set; }
    }
    public AttribStruct[] AttribArray { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a controller to fill the arrays:

```
SearchArrayModel[] src = new SearchArrayModel[1]
{
    new SearchArrayModel()
    {
        AttribArray = new SearchArrayModel.AttribStruct[]
        {
            new SearchArrayModel.AttribStruct
            {
                AttribName = atributes2.attribname, //it's in foreach loop, but it's a string value
                AttribValues = new string[] 
                {
                    values.ToString() //another string values
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
@model allegrotest.Models.SearchArrayModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowItems";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @foreach (var item in Model.AttribArray)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in item.AttribName)
        {
            <h2>@item2</h2>
        }
    }
}
```

Is it correct? I want to display all the elements from AttribArray, but in my View I have just one element

or maybe I have sth wrong in my foreach loops..

Comment: I'd start off by avoiding mutable structs...

Comment: I'm using an API and there are some structs and strange things, that's why I have problems

Comment: That's a very vague comment. Do you mean the API is exposing the mutable structs? I'd be very wary of any such API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot iterate on `string` value. To display all elements from you array you can rearrange your code to:

```
@model allegrotest.Models.SearchArrayModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowItems";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @foreach (var item in Model.AttribArray)
   {
      <h2>@item.AttribName</h2>
      foreach (var item2 in item.AttribValues)
      {
         <h3>@item2</h3>
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if `values` is a collection you probably want

```
AttribValues = values.Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray() //another string values
```